# The Fastest Permutation Code Permutating Numbers in VB NET

Tags: vb.net, algorithm, numbers, permutation

There is a famous and the fastest permutation code without any "function" for VB .Net to permutate numbers just in several rows, that I can't remember unfortunately.

Is there anyone know this code? Or know like this?

Some part of the code is here:

UPDATE: I FOUND IT. ALL THE WORKING CODES HERE:

```
Dim L(4) As Byte
Dim I As Byte
Dim K As Byte
Dim J As Byte
Dim RESULTS As String
Dim UB, UBm1 As Integer

L = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

UB = L.GetUpperBound(0)
UBm1 = UB - 1

Do
    I = UBm1
    Do While I > 0 And L(I) >= L(I + 1)
        I -= 1
    Loop
    K = L(I)
    J = UB
    Do While J > 0 And L(J) <= K
        J -= 1
    Loop

    RESULTS = L(0) & "," & L(1) & "," & L(2) & "," & L(3) & "," & L(4)

    L(I) = L(J)
    L(J) = K
    Array.Reverse(L, I + 1, UB - I)

Loop While J
```

Comment: I'm interested in knowing it since I create one too but with a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for this ...

http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/AllPerm.shtml
(2. Lexicographic order and finding the next permutation)

... ?

In case you are, the starting values for `I` and `J` are incorrect (they should be 4 and 5 instead of 3 and 4 respectively).

(I know the example uses `swap`, but that can be replaced with a single colon-delimited line.)

```
Dim L(4) As Byte
L = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

Dim K as Byte

For N as integer = 1 to 120 'No. of permutations: 5!
    Dim I As Byte = 4, J as Byte = 5

    While L(I - 1) >= L(I)
        I -= 1   
    End While
    While L(J - 1) <= L(I - 1)
        J -= 1
    End While

    K = L(I - 1) : L(I - 1) = L(J - 1) : L(J - 1) = K
    I += 1 : J = 5
    While I < J
        K = L(I - 1) : L(I - 1) = L(J - 1) : L(J - 1) = K
        I += 1 : J -= 1
    End While

    Dim RESULT as String = L(0) & "," & L(1) & "," & L(2) & "," & L(3) & "," & L(4)
    'Export / print RESULT as you like, e.g. Console.WriteLine or something
Next
```

Comment: Yes, exactly I'm looking for that, but that is written by C++ which I don't know, so I can't convert it to VB. There was a web page on the internet, which has that code in VB Net. In that code, the values has worked correctly. May be different between the codes. I need the code in VB NET. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Row "While L[I - 1]..." "I" is underlined and says "Bracketed identifier is missing closing ]" also says same thing row "While L[J - 1]" for "J". I closed it with  "]", not working. I chanced it with "()", not working again. I'm using VB .Net 2010, maybe make a difference. I really don't want to tire you out any more but may be other people can use that fast code. Thank you so much from heart.

Comment: @Serhat ahhhhhh apologies apologies I forgot that VB used parentheses instead of brackets, will edit for you now (I haven't used VB for a few months and I'm rusty)

Comment: Hahah. No problem. I had changed them to parentheses and tried the code. All results are the same now "1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,4,5"... etc. It is hard, isn't it? I was eating my brain with the code, and now you too :)

Comment: @Serhat sry again (~_~) another stupid mistake on my behalf: I wrote `I += 1 : I -= 1` which, apart from being _utterly redundant_, should be `I += 1 : J -= 1`

Comment: Same again: "1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,4,5", "1,2,3,4,5"... I'm not clever enough to understand your codes, so I can't help you but If I think on the problem all 300 days and nights long, I believe I can solve it :)

Comment: @Serhat oops I seemed to have missed another two lines as well. try now.

Comment: I gave up, I need fresh air :) Thank you so much for helping again.

Comment: @Serhat ***GASP*** never give up! just kidding, we're all human

Answer (score 0):

For obtaining a set of permutations of a natural number (*recommended* less than 10 though it can be bigger than that), this **VBA Excel** sub-routine is very fast and short. I believe it can be easy to convert it to VB.NET. Have a look.

```
Const P = 5                                     'Recommended Max P = 9
Dim m As Long, PArray(1 To 1000, 1 To P)        'Recommended Max 9! = 362880

Public Sub PermutationNaturalNumber()
    Dim Q(1 To P) As Long
    For m = 1 To P: Q(m) = m: Next: m = 0
    PermutationGenerator P, Q
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(PArray), P) = PArray: End
End Sub

Sub PermutationGenerator(n As Long, Q() As Long)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
    If n > 1 Then
        For i = 1 To n - 1
            PermutationGenerator n - 1, Q
            If n Mod 2 = 1 Then j = 1 Else j = i
            k = Q(j): Q(j) = Q(n): Q(n) = k
        Next
        PermutationGenerator n - 1, Q
    Else
        m = m + 1: For i = 1 To P: PArray(m, i) = Q(i): Next
    End If
End Sub
```

`P` can be any natural number, in this case {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Make sure you change the upper bound of `PArray` with P! meaning (`P*(P-1)*(P-2)*...*1`).